# Sort array in weird way

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
let array = ["eid_x", "eid_x", "cid_x", "cid_x"]
```

how would I sort it so it's like this?

```
let array = ["cid_x", "eid_x", "cid_x", "eid_x"]
```

The original array is in a random order, example: `eid, cid, cid, eid`.

Does anyone know how this can be sorted like in the second array?

Comment: On what basis the `sort()` should happen?

Comment: What's the logic of the sort, how do you define what comes first, second and so on?

Comment: split them into two arrays then copy from every other array into a 3rd array

Comment: @varun agarwal Not sure if I understood that, but if you mean what I think you mean it always randomizes, it could be `eid, eid, cid, cid`. Or `eid, cid, cid, eid`. Or any other combination. But I need it to end up like `cid, eid, cid, eid` etc etc

Comment: Get Off My Lawn good idea I'll try that

Comment: technically, that's not sorting at all :p

Comment: Are you sure that's called sorting??

Comment: I didn't expect that I will find a new description for randomizing an array = sort array in a weird way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the items into two arrays then grab an item off of one alternating between the two arrays within your loop (or an Array#map in this case).

```js
let array = ["eid_x", "eid_x", "cid_x", "cid_x"]

let eid = array.filter(i => i == 'eid_x')
let cid = array.filter(i => i == 'cid_x')

let result = new Array(array.length).fill(null)
  .map((i, idx) => idx % 2 == 0 ? cid.shift() : eid.shift())

console.log(result)
```